# PrimeFaces auto complete return a null object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, converters

this is my xhtml page

```
<h:form id="order_search" prependId="flase">
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                sticky="false" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="5" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                <p:outputLabel value="Customer Name : " for="ac_order" />
                <p:autoComplete id="ac_order" value="#{orderSearchController.orderFromAutoC}"
                    completeMethod="#{orderSearchController.autoCompleteOrder}" var="order"
                    itemLabel="#{order.customerName}" itemValue="#{order}"
                    converter="#{orderConverter}" forceSelection="true" />


                <p:commandButton id="selected" value="print" action="#{orderSearchController.printOrder}" />
            </h:panelGrid>          

        </h:form>
```

and this is my backing bean

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class OrderSearchController implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{orderService}")
    public OrderService orderService;
    public List<Order> allOrders;
    public List<Order> acFilterdOrders;
    public Order orderFromAutoC;

    @PostConstruct
    public void Init() {
        System.out.println("init gets called");
//      allOrders = new ArrayList<>();
//      orderFromAutoC = new Order();

        allOrders = orderService.getAllOrders();
        System.out.println("After  sssssss ");
    }

    public List<Order> autoCompleteOrder(String query) {
        acFilterdOrders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allOrders.size(); i++) {
            if (allOrders.get(i).getCustomerName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
                acFilterdOrders.add(allOrders.get(i));
            }
        }

        return acFilterdOrders;
    }

    public String printOrder() {
        System.out.println("Inside print");

        System.out.println("Inside print : "+orderFromAutoC);

        return null;
    }
    //Getters and Setters
```

}

and this is my converter code

```
@ManagedBean(name = "orderConverter")
@RequestScoped
public class OrderConverter implements Converter {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{orderService}")
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            return orderService.getOrderById(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public OrderService getOrderService() {
        return orderService;
    }

    public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }


}
```

the auto-complete component works fine but but when i tried to get the selected value from it in the backing bean it always return a null

Comment: Are'nt getAsString() supposed to return ((Order)arg2).getId() in this case?

Comment: Also there is something wrong with prependId, afaik one should not use it as it messes up ajax

Comment: ye u where right it's working

Answer (score 1):

The getAsString method is not implemented correctly as it is just returning the NULL value. The return value of getAsString method is passed as value in the getAsObject method based on which it get the value from the list. Here is an example for your reference . Value in the getAsObject method is the Id that is returned from getAsString method.

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        MessageLogBean messageLogBean = (MessageLogBean) SessionUtility.getManagedBean("messageLogBean");
        DeviceResponseDTO deviceResponseDTO = new DeviceResponseDTO();
        deviceResponseDTO.setId(Integer.parseInt(value));
        List<DeviceResponseDTO> deviceResponseDTOs = messageLogBean.getDeviceResponseDTOs();
        int index = deviceResponseDTOs.indexOf(deviceResponseDTO);
        if(null != deviceResponseDTOs && !deviceResponseDTOs.isEmpty()){
        return deviceResponseDTOs.get(index);
        }
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    if(object != null) {
        return String.valueOf(((DeviceResponseDTO) object).getId());
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```